# How to access to objects generated by GWT in plain old javascript?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am developing a web app using GWT. I use GWT to compile my java code into a JavaScript library. I would like then to use that library in plain old JavaScript in my HTML page between `<script></script>`.

For example, let's assume I have my java class to be JavaScriptized using GWT compiler:

```
package org.mycompany;

public class MyGWT {

    int myAttribute;

    public int myMethod(int value) {
        return value*2;
    }
}
```

I want to use that in JavaScript like that:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="myGWTLib.nocache.js"></script>
<script>
    var myGWT = new MyGWT();
    window.alert(myGWT.myMethod(4));
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a standard way to expose constructors, attributes and method in GWT java classes to make them accessible in plain old JavaScript?

(Maybe it is trivial, but I did not find any clear procedure to do that !).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the reason [GWT-Exporter](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/) has been created.

GWT 3.0 will add JsInterop which will basically deprecate gwt-exporter.

Comment: Terrific! I look forward seeing it fully integrated within GWT 3.0. Merci Thomas.